# MySQL DATETIME precision (joda-time, Hibernate, org.jadira.usertype, hbm2ddl)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jodatime, hbm2ddl

In my hibernate-4 entity, I am mapping a joda-time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) property using the recommended [jadira usertypes](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="timing")
public class TimingEntity {
    ...
    @Basic(optional=false)
    @Column(name="moment")
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    public DateTime getMoment() {
       ...
```

My database is MySQL. With hibernate property `hbm2ddl.auto` set to `create` value, I have the following column generated in my `timing` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `timing` (
    ...
   `moment` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

The generated `CREATE TABLE` contains the DATETIME column. The DATETIME in MySQL has only seconds precision, without fractional part. In order to enable fractional part, up to microseconds, MySQL 5.6.4 and higher [enables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) `DATETIME(precision)` columns, for example `DATETIME(3)` to have milliseconds precision.

My question is -- is there way to specify precision for my temporal fields generated with hbm2ddl? At least, is this a matter of jadira usertypes, or java.sql, or jdbc driver machinery?

**P.S.** When I manually modify the DB table to have the exact column precision I want, say, `DATETIME(3)`, everything works OK - joda DateTimes are written and read from the DB with milliseconds precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use [**@Column#columnDefinition**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition%28%29) property for it

```
@Basic(optional=false)
@Column(name="moment" columnDefinition="DATETIME(3) NOT NULL")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
public DateTime getMoment() 
{   
   ...
```

Also you can try [**@Column#precision**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#precision%28%29) property, but in documentation is written that this working only for decimals.

Comment: It did the trick, thank you! `columnDefinition` did work, `precision` did not. The drawback however is that I begin to depend on mysql in my code.

Answer (score 6):

I've found one more solution that allows not to hardcode MySQL column definition snippet in your `@Column` annotation. Define your own hibernate dialect by overriding `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`:

```
package org.yourproject;

import java.sql.Types;
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect;

public class MySQL564PlusDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {
   public MySQL564PlusDialect() {
      super();
      registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, 6, "datetime($l)" );
   }
}
```

and specify it as hibernate property `hibernate.dialect=org.yourproject.MySQL564PlusDialect` (the dialect you'll want to extend may vary, e.g. `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` instead).

Now you can adjust precision of your `DATETIME` from within `@Column` annotation by using `length` attribute:

```
@Basic(optional=false)
@Column(name="moment", length=3)
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
public DateTime getMoment() {
 ...
```

which will produce `DATETIME(3)` column definition meaning milliseconds precision. If you need the simple `DATETIME` (no fractional seconds), just don't specify length. You can use value of `length` up to 6 which would mean microseconds precision.

If you happen to use a dialect different from the above one (for example the standard `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` or maybe some other database), that will not break your code: the `length` attribute on `@Column` will be ignored.

P.S. It would be more sensible to exploit the `precision` attribute of `@Column` instead of `length`, but simple replacing of `"datetime($l)"` pattern with `"datetime($p)"` one in my own dialect implementation does not work offhand.