# hibernate - making type of column in mysql only date and not datetime

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, datetime

I am storing date in mysql database using field of type DATE :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="RECIEVING_DATE")
private Date recieving_date;

// getters and setters
```

but when hibernate saves it , date is saved in type of datetime format, i.e. it doesn't store just 2015-02-23 but 2015-02-23 00:00:00.

The code I am using for inserting the date

```
String recieving_date = request.getParameter("recieving_date");
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.sql.Date ds = null;
    try {
        Date date = df.parse(recieving_date);
        ds=new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured in parsing date : "+e1);
    }
    doc_mvmnt.setRecieving_date(ds);
```

Now , I can change type by running alter table query myself in database , but that will be painful every time. How can I tell hibernate to keep the type I want . And further , if this is possible , is it possible to define the size of varchar and integers using hibernate. Please help

Comment: how do you set date value for `recieving_date`, plz show the code related to date you set for it

Comment: I edited the post !! please see if you can help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785117/mysql-datetime-precision-joda-time-hibernate-org-jadira-usertype-hbm2ddl

Comment: no, I am trying using just hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see you are passing only `date part` of datetime to the `recieving_date` and surely the type of `recieving_date` is `java.sql.Date` (as you passing date of that type to it) so I think one of these annotations should work `@Type(type="date")` or `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` and as the second one does not work try the other and give a feedback:

```
@Column(name="RECIEVING_DATE")
@Type(type="date")
private Date recieving_date;

// getters and setters
```

if this does not solve the issue then try with modifying the getters and setters for your custom format

Comment: this Type annotation belongs to which package ??

Comment: `org.hibernate.annotations.Type`

Comment: you are very welcome, glad to see the issue has fixed.

Comment: can I use this annotation to also specify length of varchar or integers. Is there any annotation to do that ?? because by default it gives 255 chars , what if I dont want to keep that size , may be increase it or decrease to 100 chars

Comment: for length of string you can use `length` attribute of `@Column` (for length of column) annotation. you can also use the `max` attribute of `@Size` annotation (for forcing the length of value)